# Mac blogging client similar to Windows Live Writer

Tags: software-recommendation, wordpress, macos

Can someone suggest a really good blogging client for Mac OS?

I am looking for something having similar functionality like Windows Live Writer (on Windows).

Blog details: WordPress (installed on Windows).
I have a Mac laptop at home, and am trying to decide on a blogging client for WordPress.

Comment: Have you picked your blog serving stack? Wide open, anything but X, or a preference for Y?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I haven't had any exposure to live writer, but maybe you might want to give [MarsEdit](http://www.red-sweater.com/marsedit/) a try. It can interface with many different blogging systems.

Comment: Unless there are constraints on what the OP wants to use for publishing the blog - I would also choose MarsEdit as the hands-down "best" app for such an open question.

Answer (score 1):

Other than the MarsEdit, You may also want to try the [Ecto](http://illuminex.com/ecto/), or [MacJournal](http://homepage.mac.com/dschimpf/)